# Parse coefficients from a Resolve output

Tags: coefficients, parsing, resolve

I have a huge output from `Resolve` (quantifier elimination) that I must parse to extract the coefficients as numbers. Take for instance something that looks like this:

```
(c | x | y | z) \[Element] Reals && (c <= 1 && 
    c > -1 && -x - y + z == 0 && -2 c + 2 x >= -2)
```

As you can see, it outputs the basis and domain, followed by the expressions for the region the solution defines. (In this case, for instance, `c <= 1` would be what I call an "expression", as well as `-x - y + z == 0`.)

I now must extract the coefficients from each expression of this result. A reasonable output for the example above would be to build the list

```
{{1, 0, 0, 0, "<=", 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, ">", -1},
{0, -1, -1, 1, "==", 0}, {-2, 2, 0, 0, ">=", -2}}
```

but anything reasonable (in the sense it'd allow me to get the extract coefficients of each expression as numbers, while also storing the relation type) would do.

The closest hint I found in the documentation was the `Coefficient` function, but I couldn't adapt it to work in this case. Is it possible to do so? If not, are there other built-in options?

Also, I've seen a few related questions (such as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210203/69266)) that do something similar using pattern matching, but for a single expression. Would this approach be a extensible to my case? Do you have any hints on how should I proceed to apply it to my situation?

I'm quite new to Wolfram Language so I appreciate any help whatsoever.

Comment: For clarity, please provide the output that you expect for this case.

Comment: Your question is not too clear. To you mean to set all numeric coefficients to zero? Easy: expy/. x_/;NumericQ[x] ->0. Of course this may result in new coefficients != zero in this case use "//." instead of "/."

Comment: @DanielHuber My question wasn't clear enough. Following the suggestion above, I updated it with a desired output. 

Your answer helped me anyway. Do you have any tips on how would I use this type of pattern matching to, instead of substitute the values, extract them? More than that: how would I extract the ones in each expression, while settings the missing ones (i.e.: present in the basis but not in a given expression) to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extract the different comparisons using patterns by e.g.:

```
ex = (c | x | y | z) \[Element] 
    Reals && (c <= 1 && c > -1 && -x - y + z == 0 && -2 c + 2 x >= -2);

comp=Cases[ex, (Less | Greater | LessEqual | GreaterEqual | Equal)[__]  ]

(*{c <= 1, c > -1, -x - y + z == 0, -2 c + 2 x >= -2}*)
```

The coefficients of the variables you can get e.g. by:

```
coef = CoefficientRules[comp[[All, 1]], {c, x, y, z}]

(*{{{1, 0, 0, 0} -> 1}, {{1, 0, 0, 0} -> 
   1}, {{0, 1, 0, 0} -> -1, {0, 0, 1, 0} -> -1, {0, 0, 0, 1} -> 
   1}, {{1, 0, 0, 0} -> -2, {0, 1, 0, 0} -> 2}}*)
```

Or in another form:

```
coef /. Rule[x1_, x2_] :> {Pick[vars, x1 /. 1 -> True][[1]], x2}

(*{{{c, 1}}, {{c, 1}}, {{x, -1}, {y, -1}, {z, 1}}, {{c, -2}, {x, 2}}}*)
```

The right sides of the comparisons:

```
rhs=comp[[All, 2]]

(*{1, -1, 0, -2}*)
```